# How to make sure call is asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a program where user first create a file once file is created i am appending data to the file that is coming from client consistently.The below code is working as expected. I am new to nodejs so just want to get an expert opinion in case when multiple users creating and recording files on their machines at same time, will it work asynchronously or do i need to make some changes to the code ?

io.js

```
socket.on('createlogfile', function() {
            logsRecording.userLogs(function(filename) {
                socket.emit('filename', filename);
            });

        });
        socket.on('startrecording', function(obj) {
            logsRecording.recordLogs(obj);
        });
```

server.js

```
userLogs: function (callback) {
    var filename = uuid.v4() + '.log';
    var file = filePath + '/' + filename;
    fs.openSync(file, 'a',function () {
        console.log('file created');
    });
    console.log('userLogs');
    callback(filename);
},

recordLogs: function (obj) {
    var dir = './app/records/templogs'
    var fileAppend = dir + '/'+ obj.file;
    console.log('data from recording', obj.data);
            fs.readdir(dir, function(err, items) {
                items.forEach(function(file){
                    if(obj.file === file){
                        fs.appendFile(fileAppend, obj.data+ "\r\n", null, 'utf8', function (err) {
                            if (err) throw err;
                        });
                        console.log('filename in records',obj.file);
                    }
                });
            });
}
```

Comment: This will be handy - http://caolan.github.io/async/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `fs.openSync`, which is synchronous and as such can hang the event loop.

You should be using `fs.open` and callback inside it:

```
userLogs: function (callback) {
    var filename = uuid.v4() + '.log';
    var file = filePath + '/' + filename;
    fs.open(file, 'a', function (err) {
        console.log('file created');
            console.log('userLogs');
            callback(err, filename);
    });
},
```

And you can flatten `recordLogs` using [async](http://caolan.github.io/async/).

Also, it is bad practice to throw error in synchronous function, you should be passing the error in the callback.

As a last tip, `Array.forEach` is synchronous, and can hang the process, you should be using `async.each`

```
recordLogs: function (obj, callback) {
    var dir = './app/records/templogs'
    var fileAppend = dir + '/'+ obj.file;
    console.log('data from recording', obj.data);
    async.waterfall([
        (callback) => {
            fs.readdir(dir, (err, items) => {
                callback(err, items);
            });
        },
        (items, callback) => {
            async.each(items, (file, callback) => {
                if(obj.file === file) {
                    fs.appendFile(fileAppend, obj.data+ "\r\n", null, 'utf8', function (err) {
                        callback(err);
                    });
                    console.log('filename in records',obj.file);
                } else {
                    callback();
                }
            }, (err) => {
                callback(err);
            });
        }
    ], (err, file) => {
        if(callback) {
            callback(err);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thats how we write async call this syntax has bunch of errors not sure i required all these =>

Comment: `(params) => {}` is the ES6 syntax for `function (param) {}`. What do you mean by "that s how we write async call"?

Comment: I never used async thats why i was asking that's how, but these params ES6 has alot of syntax issues , Can we write this without this new ES^ syntax ?

Comment: @hussain: Sure, just replace every `() =>` by `function ()`. Yes, you will see that all asynchronous function pass the error as the first callback parameters. The syntax error is probably due to not using strict mode, try adding `'using strict';` at the top of your file.

Comment: Thanks by adding function () resolved by syntax issue now when i invoked recordLogs i see error `callback is not defined` on line  `function(err, file)  {
            callback(err); }`

Comment: My bad, forgot to add `callback` in `recordLogs`'s parameters. Alos but the `callback` code in a conditionnal in case you don't need to do anything after it like hinted in your original code.

Comment: hmm File is being appended but aplication breaks after and i see error `         if (fn === null) throw new Error("Callback was already called.");
                             ^

Error: Callback was already called.` on line `fs.appendFile(fileAppend, obj.data+ "\r\n", null, 'utf8', function (err) {
                    callback(err);
                });`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118926/discussion-between-drakasan-and-hussain).

Comment: Thank you for explaining async , I am not sure why its down voted but solution worked for me , If question and answer gets down vote that's ok but if someone explain why is being down voted that would be very helpful.